# how to build artifacts with unused java classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven based java project in which I have one class that is not used by any other code inside that project. I am generating a jar file using build artifacts option of IntelliJ-Idea but the problem is that the generated jar doesn't contain that unused class.

Kindly suggest some solution so that I can use have that unused java class in my generated jar file.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear why you don't see unused classes in the jar.

Comment: I think you need to give us more details.  There is nothing that excludes unused classes from your artifact by default.  What does your maven build look like? how are you using IntelliJ to build the artifact? are you telling intelliJ to exclude directories or 'optimize' imports before build?  More information is necessary to answer this question